# Sum of lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

I'm a little confused about when the sum of two lower semicontinuous functions is continuous. I couldn't find a neat answer to my question on this site, though there are similar ones.

Say that $f: \mathbb R^n \to [-\infty,\infty]$ is *lsc* iff $x_n \to x$ implies
$$\liminf_n(f(x_n)) \geq f(x).$$

Now suppose $f:\mathbb R^n \to [0,-\infty]$ and $g: \mathbb R^n \to (-\infty,0]$ are both lsc.

> Is $f+g$ lsc as well?

An affirmative answer would follow immediately from
$$\liminf_n(y_n + z_n) \geq \liminf_n(y_n) + \liminf_n(z_n)\tag{1}$$
for any sequence $(y_n)$ in $[0,\infty]$ and sequence $(z_n)$ in $(-\infty,0]$. For any $m \in \mathbb N$, we have
$$y_m + z_m \geq \inf_{n \geq m} y_n + \inf_{n \geq m} z_n,$$
which implies
$$\inf_{m \geq n}(y_m + z_m) \geq \inf_{n \geq m} y_n + \inf_{n \geq m} z_n.$$
Then (1) follows by letting $m \to \infty$.

I don't see what's wrong with that argument, and yet the following counterexample seems to hold as well:
$$y_n = n, \ \ z_n = -n.$$

Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: what is $\liminf (f(x))$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're saying that $0 \ge \infty+(-\infty)$ is false. Some might call it true. For any $m$, you have $\inf_{n \ge m} (y_n+z_n) = 0$, $\inf_{n \ge m} y_n = m$, and $\inf_{n \ge m} z_n = -\infty$. So indeed $$\inf_{n \geq m}(y_n + z_n) \geq \inf_{n \geq m} y_n + \inf_{n \geq m} z_n$$ $$0 \ge m+(-\infty)$$ is true. If you take the limit as $m \to \infty$, you'll get $0 \ge \infty+(-\infty)$, which we can say is true for our purposes.

So your question comes down to how you define addition on the extended reals.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was standard to say that $\infty - \infty$ is undefined. That's what I've been assuming. But I take your point.